# Why do I get an error with print(f"({x}, {y})")?

Tags: python

```
for x in range(5):
  for y in range(3):
    print(f"({x}, {y})")
```

I was trying to follow along in a python mastery class but I kept getting the following error.

```
     File "c:\Users\███\Desktop\Py Products\Tutorial\HelloWorld\app.py", line 3
    print(f"({x}, {y})")
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: You appear to be using Python 3.5 or earlier, which don't support f-strings.

Comment: please add more detail of python version you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to [format](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) the string while printing so you can use

```
for x in range(5):
  for y in range(3):
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
```

Comment: If you use a version of Python that is not outdated the f-string should work.